# Excel Formula combining text fields

Tags: excel

I want make a formula which includes text and the output will be a different text also.
Like:

```
G8 = I am Red,
G9 = I am Green, 
G10 = I am White.
```

Now, I need a formula which will give output like: 
`"Red" (in H8 field)` when I enter "I am Red" and so on for other inputs.

I have tried with 'nested if', but only 7 nested if can be added, whereas I have at least 40+ values to input and need to get different output for those input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column G starting G8, do the following:

1. Type in H8: `=RIGHT(G8,LEN(G8)-MAX(IF(MID(G8,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(G8))),1)=" ",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(G8))),0)))`.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).
3. Autofill formula down your range.

It will return the last "word" in a string, or more exactly - part of string between the last space and its end, regardless of actual symbols.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfkk1cqy1z0o3pz/ColorName.xlsx

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter! actually, I want a different output in the "H8" column for every different input in G8!     like:      `G8 = I am Red,         in H8 result would be : R1
G9 = I am Green,       in H9 result would be : R3   
G10 = I am White.      in H10 result would be : R12 `                        and so on. which means for every single combination of text there will be a different output. Please comment.

Comment: @user2042520 could you please add an output sample to your initial question - I still don't understand what you need exactly...

Comment: Please visit the following link. In column A there are some inputs and in Column B there are some inputs also. IN EVERY ROW, For combinations of column A and B, the result is given on the next column "Result". [sample excel file](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?6fgjbiu2egj0syn). thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A vlookup may work here.  You would enter all data combinations, and then use vlookup, based on the "I am red" column, which would find the corresponding value in the table and return it.  Depending on the type of data, you may have better success with the index and match method instead of vlookup.

Comment: hi!! I have added a sample file > <http://www.mediafire.com/view/?6fgjbiu2egj0syn>. would you please check and help me with any formula that will give the "result" for certain combinations of A and B columns.

Comment: Here is the forumla that i used: =INDEX(DataAndResult,MATCH(A5&B5,CombinedData,0),2)  The DataAndResult and CombinedData are named ranges that were used for the lookup.  Not sure how to send sample, or I would send you it.